# Get all inbox messages with Gmail API using PHP

Tags: php, gmail-api

How can I get all inbox messages using Gmail API with PHP? I can just get message ID, and nothing beyond that. I need to fetch Subject, Sender and Message Text.

```
<?php

$list = $gmail->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me', ['maxResults' => 10000, 'q' => 'category:primary']);

$messageList = $list->getMessages();

$client->setUseBatch(true);
$batch = new Google_Http_Batch($client);

foreach($messageList as $mlist){
    $batch->add($gmail->users_messages->get('me', $mlist->id, ['format' => 'raw']), $mlist->id);
}

$batchMessages = $batch->execute();
$inboxMessage = [];

foreach($batchMessages as $dMessage){
    $messageId = $dMessage->id;
    $messageSnippet = $dMessage->snippet;

    $dcMessage = base64url_decode($dMessage->getRaw());

    $params['include_bodies'] = true;
    $params['decode_bodies'] = true;
    $params['decode_headers'] = true;

    $mimeDecode = new Mail_mimeDecode($dcMessage);
    $mimeSubject = $mimeDecode->decode($params)->headers['subject'];

    $inboxMessage[] = [
        'messageId' => $messageId,
        'messageSubject' => $messageSubject
    ];
}

?>
```

Comment: I think you have to call the message.get with the id of the message to actually get that information. When calling the get method the information will be contained in the parameter payload.headers[] as described here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is how i did it.

```
<?php

$list = $gmail->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me', [
    'maxResults' => 10,
    'q' => $search
]);

$messageList = $list->getMessages();
$inboxMessage = [];

foreach($messageList as $mlist) {
    $optParamsGet2['format'] = 'full';
    $single_message = $gmail->users_messages->get('me', $mlist->id, $optParamsGet2);

    $message_id = $mlist->id;
    $headers = $single_message->getPayload()->getHeaders();
    $snippet = $single_message->getSnippet();

    foreach($headers as $single) {
        if ($single->getName() == 'Subject') {
            $message_subject = $single->getValue();
        } elseif ($single->getName() == 'Date') {
            $message_date = $single->getValue();
            $message_date = date('M jS Y h:i A', strtotime($message_date));
        } elseif ($single->getName() == 'From') {
            $message_sender = $single->getValue();
            $message_sender = str_replace('"', '', $message_sender);
        }
    }

    $inboxMessage[] = [
        'messageId' => $message_id,
        'messageSnippet' => $snippet,
        'messageSubject' => $message_subject,
        'messageDate' => $message_date,
        'messageSender' => $message_sender
    ];
}

?>
```

Comment: Hi shimi, could send me  a full function of this? I need it so much. this is my email : samphors.info@gmail.com

Comment: Can you share the full function with everyone please?

Comment: Thanks Dejan. That is what I exactly wanted.

Comment: i also need this project